# Remove additional padding around addonBefore and addonAfter on Input element

Tags: react-bootstrap

I have an addonBefore DropdownButton and an addonAfter button in a Input element.

They work, but they are creating additional padding around the elements.

[image]

How do I prevent this?

```
const searchDropDown = (
  <DropdownButton title="Dropdown">
    <MenuItem eventKey="1">Dropdown link</MenuItem>
    <MenuItem eventKey="2">Dropdown link</MenuItem>
  </DropdownButton>
);

const searchButton = (
  <button className="fa fa-search" />
);

return (
  <form className={styles.SearchBar}>

    <Input
      type="text"
      addonBefore={searchDropDown}
      addonAfter={searchButton}
      placeholder="Search..."
    />
  </form>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `bsSize='small'` or xsmall to the input itself or to the buttons. This helped me.